# GL_TRIANGLES filling makes curve straight

Tags: opengl

**EDIT: I had written GL_POLYGONS instead of GL_TRIANGLES, sorry**

I have a shape which comprises of a 2 joined bezier curves. I'm trying to fill it using GL_TRIANGLES about an internal point. Here are the results:

[image]

On the right is the actual shape displayed via GL_LINE_STRIP.
On the left is the result after GL_TRIANGLES after giving the points in a triangular way.

As you can see, the curvy shape has disappeared and instead it's (almost) a straight edge.

Any idea how can I fix this? Or maybe a better way to fill such shapes?

Comment: All the `GL_QUAD*` and `GL_POLYGON` types were deprecated with OpenGL 3.0. Generate triangles instead.

Comment: I'm sorry I had written GL_POLYGONS instead of GL_TRIANGLES, my bad. I'm in fact triangulating the required points to fill the shape in.

Answer (score 3):

Things supplied to `GL_POLYGON` must be convex. Your object is concave.

If you know that your shape is always going to appear convex if approached from one direction — e.g. with your shape I can definitely say that any horizontal line is going to hit exactly two boundaries — then you can approach it as a triangle strip.

If you don't know anything at all about your polygon in advance, you need to look into tesselation, which is any number of algorithms for reducing an arbitrary polygon to a list of convex polygons that cover the same area. GLU contains a tesselator for which simple use [is described here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/glu.htm). The [Wikipedia article on triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_clipping) neatly summarises the most popular algorithms if you want to implement your own, and Mesa provides an open source implementation of GLU if your platform doesn't already have it.

Comment: I'm sorry I had written GL_POLYGONS instead of GL_TRIANGLES, my bad. I'm infact triangulating the required points to fill the shape in.

Comment: @user1265125 what do you see if you switch `glPolygonMode` to `GL_LINE`?

Comment: `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_LINE);`, still straight edges. Although filling is a big irregular now.

Comment: That would suggest your triangulation really does include those lines. Are you using GLU or anything else off the shelf?

Comment: But I'm using the exact same function (minus the triangulation) to generate the curves on the left and on the right. So my shape is definitely correct!